# Diablo 3, unknown creature

Tags: diablo-iii

In diablo 3, there is this creature that keeps popping up, and i am not sure what it is. I thought it was a treasure goblin, but everyone keeps talking about canceling it's portal, or whatever. After it dies, giving me a lot of gold and stuff, it leaves a rainbow portal. i went through it, which led me to this creepy, girly world where unicorns, care bears, and flowers try to kill me. after clearing the map, i went back through it, and it took me back to the same place. it happened when i was going through these towers, disabling something. Is it a treasure goblin or not?

Comment: In the theme of Jeopardy, "What is Whimsyshire?"

Comment: Congrats, you found Diablo 3's version of the 'Cow Level'

Answer (score 14):

Yes, it is a Treasure Goblin. More specifically, it is a **Rainbow Treasure Goblin**. These fine creatures spawn entrances to [Whimsydale](http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Whimsydale) (which is different to Whimsyshire, at least in name).

Answer (score 1):

Yep, it's definitely a treasure goblin.  You got lucky, though, and it opened a portal to Whimsyshire.  It's a "secret" area (but not really so secret), where everything is brighter and more cheerful, and you fight things like horses, unicorns, flowers, and teddy bears.  It's meant to be a dramatic departure from the rest of Diablo 3.

Comment: As a side note, the level was actually an inside joke based on a fan comment sometime before the release of Diablo 3. Unfortunately all related pages are blocked for me at work so I can't provide a citation at the moment.

Comment: @Phaeze Its a reference to a screenshot (of Act 1) revealed prior to the release of Diablo 3. In this screenshot was a rainbow and many people complained that the game was too bright and cheery because of it compared to Diablo 1/2. See: http://www.diablowiki.net/Art_controversy

Comment: @Steven that's the one thanks for filling that in.

Comment: Ironically that area just ends up being creepy and/or bizarre due to the weird, unattractive nature of the enemies in that area, the splotchy overly-bright coloring that looks like a child's fingerpaint image, and the unsettling, un-melodic soundtrack that drones on in the background. Of course, that was probably intentional.